# Unified Fix for ALL CORS errors in the same app

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, cors

I know many people have had issues with CORS. I have searched a lot and I have found many answers but I still have errors. The things I tried solved some errors but caused other, all CORS errors...

In my app, I use two API's: an API for the authentication and the mysql requests, the other one is openweathermap. For the latter, I found a solution adding `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` in front of the API url (http://api.openweathermap.org/ ...). It works well. But I still a errors when I use my own API.

I tried using the same method but my axios call gets a 404.

```
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/my_api.test/api/login 404 (Invalid host)
```

For the login, it works but all other API calls fail. I found that I could add headers in my API to help me:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Authorization");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
```

Adding this allows other API calls to succeed but the login fails... Is there a way to make all my API calls to be successful ?

**Error message:**

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://my_api.test/api/login' from origin
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight
request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.
```

Comment: I think you need to change some code in your backend as well. In which framework / language did you write your API?

Comment: I used Laravel for the backend.

Comment: @Thbwun how is your `login` endpoint different than other api endpoints?

Comment: The login is in another controller and the url is in another route file (`api.php` for the login and `web.php` for the others). All functions in my controllers end with a `return response()->json([]);` either containing the newly created user or the data I retrieve from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is both the problem and the solution. There is a file called `cors.php` in the config folder to deal with this. By default only the path 'api/*' is managed. Adding the headers solved the problem for the other paths but caused an error for the path 'api/*'.

```
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.
```

**By simply replacing `api/*` by `/*` in `config/cors.php`**, I can access all paths of my API without having CORS errors.